# ActionScript 3 - Timer/Countdown

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, flash-cs6

I'm trying to make timer which goes up 1 every second and this is displayed in a dynamic text box called timer_txt.

When the timer reaches 60 secounds I want to display a screen, to do this I will use gameOver.visible = true;. But how would I get the timer to completely stop?

Also I want the car object to stop the timer completely when it hits the finish movie clip and to display the finshed time in a dynamic text box called finishTime. This is all on the same frame.

Would anyone please help me ?

This is the code I currently have to calculated the time but I'm currently having no luck.

```
var currentTime:int = getTimer();

//Setting the timer to 0.
var Secounds = 0;


function timer():void{
 //Adding 1 to secounds var. 
 Secounds +=1;
```

}

```
setInterval(timer,1000);
 trace(Secounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timer` instead of `setInterval`.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 60);
```

1000 — is a delay in ms.
60 — is a repeat count.

Timer will fire every second for one minute.

Next, add an event listener.

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, complete);
```

and start the timer:

```
timer.start();
```

The tick method will fired (called) every second.
After 1 minute the complete method will fired (called).

To stop the timer call `timer.stop();`